# What does the Apple Command key symbol (⌘) mean on Icelandic road signs?

Tags: iceland, road-signs

I've just returned from a holiday in Iceland (I can heartily recommend it, BTW). I took a break from Stack Exchange as well, but I guess one can never stop being a moderator... I couldn't help but notice the Apple Command key symbol, the logo of our sister site [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

[image]

being used on a couple of road signs, e.g. this one near the [Háifoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1ifoss) waterfall:

[image]

The Ask Different logo is derived from the [Command key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key) – we can't use an Apple-like logo since we're "not affiliated with or endorsed by Apple Inc. in any way." (see our footer).

Sometimes, a modified version with a caret ('roof') is used:

[image]

I thought I found the answer on an information board just inside [Hveragerði](http://www.hveragerdi.is/English/) which says it's for Hot Spring Areas:

[image]

but that doesn't make sense; the Háifoss is 'just' a waterfall and the Ráðhús is a town hall.

Bonus question: is this something Iceland specific or is it used in other countries as well?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the definitive answer when I was typing this question; while inserting the ⌘ in the question's title and hovering over it, the dialog showed me it's a Place of Interest Sign:

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looped_square), it's called a Looped Square and it's mainly used for this specific purpose in the Scandinavian countries:

> It is also known as the place of interest sign when used on information signs, a practice which started in Finland in the 1950s, spreading to the other Nordic countries in the 1960s.

To my defense, before Iceland I've only been to Helsinki as a tourist. (But maybe I should've checked the Wikipedia page about the Command Key first.)

Comment: If you're wondering why Apple chose this symbol for the Command key, Andy Hertzfeld tells the tale: [Swedish Campground](https://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Swedish_Campground.txt) (there's more information in the comments below)

Comment: So in fact, the good question to ask is "Why is the Swedish roadsign looped square symbol found on Apple keyboards?" :)

Comment: @ZachLipton My favourite comment in the page you linked: "My coworkers have referred to this key as the quadcopter key."